# What is the proper way to load user data from database and pass it into intent extras

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

The project im working on allow the user to register and login and all works perfectly until I spotted something wrong with the code. It doesn't count as an error because the compiler don't think its an error. Its just a bug or whatever people call it is. So here's what happened . The user login to their account, the database transfer their data into `intent extras`. then on the next activities, the username, coins and gems appears on top of the page so that the user know how much coins they have left. For testing purpose, i added add coin and decrease coin button. still, the code works perfectly. But after the user log out and relogin, the `coins` backs to the original amount. I know the problem caused by putting a value on the coin variable in `User.java` class. And still while logging in I put the default value of coins and gems for the user in the intent extras. I just cant find my way on how to put the value from database to the intent extras while user logging in.
so heres the code for login activity

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Check user input is correct or not
            if (validate()) {

                //Get values from EditText fields
                String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                User player1 = new User(null, null, Email, Password);
                //Authenticate user
                User currentUser = myDb.Authenticate(player1);

                //Check Authentication is successful or not
                if (currentUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Success");

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("P_ID", currentUser.getId());
                    extras.putString("P_NAME", currentUser.getName());
                    extras.putInt("P_COINS", currentUser.getCoins());
                    extras.putInt("P_GEMS", currentUser.getGems());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    //User Logged in Failed
                    System.out.println("Failed");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

the homeactivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  //Set fullscreen and no title//////////
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

///////////////////////////////////////

```
  setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

  myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

  Intent intent = getIntent();
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

  pid = extras.getString("P_ID");
  pname = extras.getString("P_NAME");
  pcoins = extras.getInt("P_COINS");
  pgems = extras.getInt("P_GEMS");

  nametxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playernametext);
  coinstxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playercoinstext);
  gemstxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playergemstext);

  addcoin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
  decoin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.decbtn);

  nametxt.setText(" " +String.valueOf(pname) +" ");
  coinstxt.setText(" Coins : " +String.valueOf(pcoins) +" ");
  gemstxt.setText(" Gems : " +String.valueOf(pgems) +" ");

  addcoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      pcoins += 10;
      boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateUser(pid, pname, String.valueOf(pcoins), String.valueOf(pgems));
      if (isUpdate == true) {
        nametxt.setText(" " +String.valueOf(pname) +" ");
  coinstxt.setText(" Coins : " +String.valueOf(pcoins) +" ");
  gemstxt.setText(" Gems : " +String.valueOf(pgems) +" ");
      }
    }
  });

  decoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      pcoins -= 10;
      boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateUser(pid, pname, String.valueOf(pcoins), String.valueOf(pgems));
      if (isUpdate == true) {
        nametxt.setText(" " +String.valueOf(pname) +" ");
  coinstxt.setText(" Coins : " +String.valueOf(pcoins) +" ");
  gemstxt.setText(" Gems : " +String.valueOf(pgems) +" ");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

and of course the user class

```
public class User {
  public String id;
  public String userName;
  public String email;
  public String password;
  public int coins = 1000;
  public int gems = 10;

  public User(String id, String userName, String email, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.userName;
  }

  public void addCoins(int addAmount) {
    this.coins = addAmount;
  }

  public void decCoins(int decAmount) {
    this.coins = decAmount;
  }

  public int getCoins() {
    return this.coins;
  }

  public void addGems(int addAmount) {
    this.gems = addAmount;
  }

  public void decGems(int decAmount) {
    this.gems = decAmount;
  }

  public int getGems() {
    return this.gems;
  }
}
```

Honestly, my brain lacks of logic. Thats why i come here, to see whether my code does make sense.
And please, if you don't understand what i mean, just ask me which parts and please just dont immediately flag my question. Im really bad at english, trust me.

Comment: Do you update the new coins value in database on add coin or decrease coin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest only passing the userid (which should never change) and then always getting the values coins etc from the database and also only changing them in the database (followed by resetting the displayed values from the values in the database).

You would then not have the issue of trying to juggle two sets of data you would then rely on the real data i.e. that in the database.

### Working Example

The following is some code that goes through the basics.

When it starts the MainActivity, immediately starts the LoginActivity when you login then it takes you to the HomeActivity. This display the current Userid, Username, coins (initially 0) and gems.

There are 2 buttons **Add10Coins** and **Add10gems** clicking them will apply the new values to the DB displaying the updated values. If you stop the App and rerun, login then the values will be as they were.

Passing values wise, although the LoginActivity sets 3 Intent Extra values only one is used (the userid as a long) by the HomeActivity, but as per the values display all are accessible. If another activity is started then all you have to do is pass the userid via the intent.

The code isn't what I'd call complex but I'd certainly suggest going through it and try to understand it.

### user.java

I've added some methods and also added some Constants, this is now :-

```
public class User {

    public static final int ADJUSTTYPE_ADD = 1;
    public static final int ADJUSTTYPE_REPLACE = 2;
    public static final int ADJUSTTYPE_MULTIPLY = 3;
    public static final int ADJUSTTYPE_DIVIDE = 4;

    String id;
    String userName;
    String email;
    String password;
    int coins;
    int gems;

    public User(String id, String userName, String email, String password) {

        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        //And so on. Don't mind this

    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setCoins(int coins) {
        this.coins = coins;
    }

    public int getCoins() {
        return this.coins;
    }

    public void setGems(int gems) {
        this.gems = gems;
    }

    public int getGems() {
        return this.gems;
    }

    public long getLongId() {
        long id;
        try {
            id = Long.valueOf(this.id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

### DatabaseHelper.java

This has been written from scratch based upon not the most stringent inspection of your code, it will largely be affected by my styling/usage techniques but not to the extent that I'd apply for real development.

Within this is the method **adjustCoinsAndOrGems** this is what is used to update the gems or coins in the DB and also in the returned User (so that a synchronised version of the User is returned, not that this returned use is used (I personally prefer to access the database as long as it's not an issue (e.g. noticeably affects performance)))

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mygame.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_USER = "user";
    public static final String COL_USER_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String COL_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    public static final String COL_USER_PASWWORD = "user_password";
    public static final String COL_USER_COINS = "user_coins";
    public static final String COL_USER_GEMS = "user_gems";

    public static final String TBL_PLAYER = "player";
    public static final String COL_PLYAER_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_PLAYER_OWNINGUSER = "player_owninguser";
    public static final String COL_PLAYER_NAME = "player_name";
    //...... other columns


    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crt_tbl_user = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_USER + "(" +
                COL_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_USER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
                COL_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
                COL_USER_PASWWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                COL_USER_COINS + " INTEGER," +
                COL_USER_GEMS + " INTEGER" +
                ")";

        String crt_tbl_player = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_PLAYER + "(" +
                COL_PLYAER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_PLAYER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                COL_PLAYER_OWNINGUSER + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TBL_USER + "(" + COL_USER_ID + ")" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl_user);
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl_player);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    /*
        Note core add but not intended to be used directly
        Note this assumes that checks are done to ensure that name, email and password
            have been provided
     */
    private long addUser(Long id, String name, String email, String password, int coins, int gems) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (id > 0) {
            cv.put(COL_USER_ID,id);
        }
        if (name.length() > 0) {
            cv.put(COL_USER_NAME,name);
        }
        if (email.length() > 0 ) {
            cv.put(COL_USER_EMAIL,email);
        }
        if (password.length() > 0) {
            cv.put(COL_USER_PASWWORD,password);
        }
        cv.put(COL_USER_COINS,coins);
        cv.put(COL_USER_GEMS,gems);
        if (cv.size() < 1) return -1; //<<<<<<<<<< return if nothing to add
        return mDB.insert(TBL_USER,null,cv);
    }

    /*
        For add with just name, email and password (normal usage)
     */
    public long addUser(String name, String email, String password) {
        return this.addUser(-1L,name,email,password,0,0);
    }

    /*
        For adding a user setting the coins and gems (special usage)
     */
    public long addUserSettingCoinsAndGems(String name, String email, String password, int coins, int gems) {
        return  this.addUser(-1L,name,email,password,coins,gems);
    }

    public User getUser(long id) {
        User rv = new User("-1","",",",""); // Invalid user
        String whereclause = COL_USER_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_USER,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv.setId(String.valueOf(id));
            rv.setName(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_NAME)));
            rv.setEmail(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_EMAIL)));
            rv.setPassword(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_PASWWORD)));
            rv.setCoins(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_COINS)));
            rv.setGems(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_GEMS)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public User getUser(String userid) {
        String whereclause = COL_USER_ID + "=?";

        User rv = new User("-1","",",",""); // Invalid user
        long id;
        try {
            id = Long.valueOf(userid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return rv;
        }
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};

        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_USER,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv.setId(String.valueOf(id));
            rv.setName(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_NAME)));
            rv.setEmail(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_EMAIL)));
            rv.setPassword(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_PASWWORD)));
            rv.setCoins(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_COINS)));
            rv.setGems(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_GEMS)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public User getUser(String email, String password) {
        User rv = new User("-1","","","");
        String whereclause = COL_USER_EMAIL + "=? AND " + COL_USER_PASWWORD + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{email,password};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_USER,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv.setId( String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_ID))));
            rv.setName(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_NAME)));
            rv.setEmail(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_EMAIL)));
            rv.setPassword(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_PASWWORD)));
            rv.setCoins(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_COINS)));
            rv.setGems(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_GEMS)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public User adjustCoinsAndOrGems(User u, int coins, int coin_adjustmode, int gems, int gem_adjustmode) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        User rv;
        User user_fromDB = getUser(u.getId());
        if (user_fromDB.id.equals("-1")) return u; // User not found so return
        switch (coin_adjustmode) {
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_REPLACE:
                cv.put(COL_USER_COINS,coins);
                break;
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_ADD:
                if (coins != 0) {
                    cv.put(COL_USER_COINS,user_fromDB.getCoins() + coins);
                }
                break;
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_MULTIPLY:
                if (coins > 0) {
                    cv.put(COL_USER_COINS,user_fromDB.getCoins() * coins);
                }
                break;
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_DIVIDE:
                if (coins > 0) {
                    cv.put(COL_USER_COINS,user_fromDB.getCoins() / coins);
                }
                break;
        }
        switch (gem_adjustmode) {
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_REPLACE:
                cv.put(COL_USER_GEMS,gems);
                break;
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_ADD:
                if (gems != 0) {
                    cv.put(COL_USER_GEMS,user_fromDB.getGems() + gems);
                }
                break;
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_MULTIPLY:
                if (gems > 0) {
                    cv.put(COL_USER_GEMS,user_fromDB.getGems() * gems);
                }
                break;
            case User.ADJUSTTYPE_DIVIDE:
                if (gems > 0) {
                    cv.put(COL_USER_GEMS,user_fromDB.getGems() / gems);
                }
                break;
        }
        if (cv.size() < 1) return u;
        String whereclause = COL_USER_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{u.getId()};
        mDB.update(TBL_USER,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
        return getUser(user_fromDB.getId());
    }

    public boolean authenticateUser(String email, String password) {
        User u = getUser(email,password);
        return (u.getLongId() > 0);
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

Very simple activity that starts the LoginActivity and when finally returned to does nothing (so you might as well kill the app).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mMessage;
    DatabaseHelper mDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMessage = this.findViewById(R.id.message);
        mDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeTestingUsers();


        // Immediately start Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMessage.setText("Welcome back");
    }

    private void addSomeTestingUsers() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.TBL_USER) > 0) return;
        mDB.addUser("Fred","fred@fredmal.com","password");
        mDB.addUser("Mary","mary@mary.email.com","password");
    }
}
```

### LoginActivity

This is pretty straightforward note that as it stands you have to Login and that the emails and passwords for the 2 users are coded in the MainActivity. When supplied correctly the HomeActivivty is started :-

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static final String INTENTKEY_USERNAME = "IK_USERNAME";
public static final String INTENTKEY_USERID = "IK_USERID";
public static final String INTENTKEY_STRINGUSERID = "IK_USERIDSTRING";

Button mloginbtn;
EditText mEmail,mPassword;
Context mContext;
DatabaseHelper mDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mContext = this;
    mloginbtn = this.findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    mEmail = this.findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = this.findViewById(R.id.password);
    mDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    mloginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            handleAuthentication();
        }
    });
}

private void handleAuthentication() {
    if (mDB.authenticateUser(mEmail.getText().toString(),mPassword.getText().toString())) {
        User u = mDB.getUser(mEmail.getText().toString(),mPassword.getText().toString());
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext,HomeActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(INTENTKEY_USERNAME,u.getName());
        i.putExtra(INTENTKEY_USERID,u.getLongId());
        i.putExtra(INTENTKEY_STRINGUSERID,u.getId());
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

### HomeActivity

For brevity, this has been used to display the coins and gems, it to is pretty basic and relies upon methods in the DatabaseHelper to do much of the work.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mUserameTextView, mUseridTextView, mCoinsTextView, mGemsTextView;
    Button mAdd10Coins, mAdd10Gems,mDone;
    User mUser;
    long mUserid;
    Context mContext;
    DatabaseHelper mDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mContext = this;
        mDB = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);

        mUserameTextView = this.findViewById(R.id.username);
        mUseridTextView = this.findViewById(R.id.userid);
        mCoinsTextView = this.findViewById(R.id.coins);
        mGemsTextView = this.findViewById(R.id.gems);

        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        mUserid = i.getLongExtra(LoginActivity.INTENTKEY_USERID,-1);
        mUser = mDB.getUser(mUserid);
        refreshDisplay();
        initButtons();
    }

    private void initButtons() {
        mAdd10Coins = this.findViewById(R.id.add10coins);
        mAdd10Coins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDB.adjustCoinsAndOrGems(mUser,10,User.ADJUSTTYPE_ADD,0,User.ADJUSTTYPE_ADD);
                mUser = mDB.getUser(mUserid);
                refreshDisplay();
            }
        });
        mAdd10Gems = this.findViewById(R.id.add10gems);
        mAdd10Gems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDB.adjustCoinsAndOrGems(mUser,0, User.ADJUSTTYPE_ADD,10,User.ADJUSTTYPE_ADD);
                mUser = mDB.getUser(mUserid);
                refreshDisplay();
            }
        });

        mDone = this.findViewById(R.id.done);
        mDB = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        mDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        mUseridTextView.setText(mUser.getId());
        mUserameTextView.setText(mUser.getName());
        mCoinsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mUser.getCoins()));
        mGemsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mUser.getGems()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Now this makes sense rather than goes back and forth passing the data multiple times

Comment: can i use this method to save the player inventory?

Comment: And question, why does -1 value in `new User("-1")`parameter in the database did? or `addUser(-1L)` is it a must to have -1 value?

Comment: @NikolaiAleksandrovsk -1 isn't a must. However, on it's own SQLite will never auto generate -1, as such it's a good indication that the user has not been obtained from the database (0 or any negative number would suffice as they are all numbers that wouldn't be auto generated).

Comment: @NikolaiAleksandrovsk yes, well at least the principle of relying upon the database. It's when/if speed becomes an inhibiting factor that you'd start to try alternatives but at the expense of possibly losing data (inventory items).

Comment: I dont really understand what you're trying to say, but , is it a good practice to use this method for saving inventory? I mean what are the goods and bads

Comment: Pretty sure yes. that is invetory items would be owned by a player owned by a user so you'd pass the id of the currently logged in user and the id of the currently selected player and from there should be able to get everything related to the player and the user.

Comment: Okey now i get it